# sort and add empty values to an array if needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that i want counted and sorted. How can i achieve this? My tries have results in infinitiy loops.

I want this array

```
[
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-05", timestamp: "2017-12-05 15:58:25", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-06", timestamp: "2017-12-06 10:13:12", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-06", timestamp: "2017-12-07 09:38:12", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-08", timestamp: "2017-12-08 09:35:25", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-11", timestamp: "2017-12-11 11:25:31", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-12", timestamp: "2017-12-12 15:05:17", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-13", timestamp: "2017-12-13 11:08:40", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 100, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-15", timestamp: "2017-12-15 11:51:33", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-18", timestamp: "2017-12-18 11:04:56", …}
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-15", timestamp: "2017-12-18 12:04:56", …}
]
```

to look like this array based/sorted on **Date_date**

(Date_date: "2017-12-01" does not exist, so value is 0, Date_date: "2017-12-06" exists two times, so value is 2)

```
[0,0,0,0...,1,2,0,1...]
```

Ok if new array is created. No jquery.

EDIT:
Sorry, here is my tried code that loops without stop

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j <= b.length; j++){
        if(parseInt(a[i].Date_date.substring(8))-1==j){
            var num = b[j];
            b[j] = num+1;
        }
        else{
            var num = b[j];
            b[j] = num+0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update this post with the code that you've already tried,

Comment: Add your tried code, instead of directly asking for solution. Also, add the date range.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: So you want `Given a start date and end date, find how often every day occurs inside the array` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort your array on date and then create an object look up based on `Date_date`. Then get the first and last date from the sorted array and create date object for the first day of the month and last day of the month. Then using while loop, add records by checking in the object lookup till the last date.

```js
var data = [{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-05", timestamp: "2017-12-05 15:58:25"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-06", timestamp: "2017-12-06 10:13:12"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-06", timestamp: "2017-12-07 09:38:12"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-08", timestamp: "2017-12-08 09:35:25"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-11", timestamp: "2017-12-11 11:25:31"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-12", timestamp: "2017-12-12 15:05:17"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-13", timestamp: "2017-12-13 11:08:40"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 100, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-15", timestamp: "2017-12-15 11:51:33"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-18", timestamp: "2017-12-18 11:04:56"},{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-15", timestamp: "2017-12-18 12:04:56"},];

var dateCount = data
   .sort((a,b) => new Date(a.Date_date) - new Date(b.Date_date))
   .reduce((r, o) => {
      r[o.Date_date] = r[o.Date_date] || [];
      r[o.Date_date].push(o)
      return r;
  }, {});

//Get the first date from the sorted array
var date1 = new Date(data[0].Date_date);
var firstDay = new Date(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), 2);

//Get the last date from the sorted array
var date2 = new Date(data[data.length - 1].Date_date);
var lastDay = new Date(date2.getFullYear(), date2.getMonth() + 1, 1);

var result = [];
while(firstDay <= lastDay){
  var count = (dateCount[firstDay.toISOString().split('T')[0]] || []).length;
  result.push(count);
  firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hassan, it seems that day 00 is replacing day 31. The array is 31 in lenght, but day 5 is in [5] and should be in pos [4]. How can i fix this? Do i make a new question?

Comment: Updated the solution, please check now.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get the number of times each date appears in an array. So I've iterated over every object in the array using `data.forEach`.

Notice that I am keeping track of the date counts in an object named `counter`.

Then, I am using `data.map` to map every object in the array to an item in a new array. So, for every item in the `data` array, I return the count of times it was observed.

You can read more about [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you're not familiar with them.

```js
var data = [
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-05", timestamp: "2017-12-05 15:58:25"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-06", timestamp: "2017-12-06 10:13:12"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-06", timestamp: "2017-12-07 09:38:12"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-08", timestamp: "2017-12-08 09:35:25"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-11", timestamp: "2017-12-11 11:25:31"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-12", timestamp: "2017-12-12 15:05:17"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-13", timestamp: "2017-12-13 11:08:40"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 100, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-15", timestamp: "2017-12-15 11:51:33"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-18", timestamp: "2017-12-18 11:04:56"},
{activityId: 201609011024550000, Employee_employeeId: 4075, projectId: 300000000000000200, Date_date: "2017-12-15", timestamp: "2017-12-18 12:04:56"}
];

var counter = {};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  var date = item.Date_date;
  
  if(!!counter[date]) {
    counter[date]++;
  } else {
    counter[date] = 1;
  }
});

console.log("Date-wise counts: ", counter);

var result = data.map(function(item) {
  return counter[item.Date_date];
});

console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: Hi Nisarg and thanks for the answer. This looks on the right path, i still need the missing dates to be added aswell ("2017-12-01": 0,). Do i make a new loop and create a new array using the counter?

Comment: @Softy Yes, something like that. I missed that part in the question. Do you want me to show how?

Comment: no thats alright, im gonna use the answer provided by Hassan. Your answer will still be upvoted by me (my reputation is under 15 so the vote will kick in later)